# Como remover todas as Classes de um elemento usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ao invés de eu remover todas as classes individualmente utilizando o remove class:

`$("#div").removeClass('classe')`

Para cada classe que um elemento possa ter, existe alguma função que pode ser chamada e remover todas as classes em um elemento?

Necessito disto em jQuery ou em Javascript.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("#div").removeClass();
```

Chamar `removeClass` sem parâmetros removerá todas as classes do item.

Você também pode usar (mas não é necessariamente recomendado, o caminho correto é aquele acima):

```
$("#div").removeAttr('class');
$("#div").attr('class', '');
$('#div')[0].className = '';
```

Se você não tivesse jQuery, então isso seria praticamente sua única opção:

```
document.getElementById('div').className = '';
```

Answer (score 9):

Basta você utilizar o método `removeClass` sem parâmetros:

```
$("#div").removeClass();
```

[Documentação](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)